# Buscar Dados em um ListView com ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Tenho um listView com JSONTask para buscar no meu banco de dados está tudo Ok.

Neste listView eu tenho varios campos, Placa, Marca, Modelo, Ano. etc.

Vi alguns exemplos na net mas é pra busca simples de um única linha tentei colocar no meu código mas não deu muito certo, no meu caso preciso apenas buscar a placa do veículo.

Veja meu código que fiz...

```
       private ListView lvRevistas;

public static String CodigoAcessoEmpresa;
public static String PlacaVeiculo;
private EditText etSearch;
// Search EditText


RevistaAdpter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvRevistas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvRevista);

    etSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    PlacaVeiculo = (intent.getStringExtra("Placa"));

    // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

//Restaura as preferencias gravadas
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Login_Empresa.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    CodigoAcessoEmpresa = (settings.getString("PrefUsuario", ""));

    if(CodigoAcessoEmpresa != null && !CodigoAcessoEmpresa.trim().isEmpty()) {
        CodigoAcessoEmpresa ="M001P4";
    }

    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        new JSONTask().execute("http://www.promastersolution.com.br/x7890_IOS/garageiro/listar_veiculos.php?tipo_os=android&id_empresa="+CodigoAcessoEmpresa);

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder Checkbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        Checkbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.error);
        Checkbuilder.setTitle("Erro");
        Checkbuilder.setMessage("Sem conexão com internet...");

        Checkbuilder.setPositiveButton("Tentar novamente", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                new JSONTask().execute("http://www.promastersolution.com.br/x7890_IOS/garageiro/listar_veiculos.php?tipo_os=android&id_empresa="+CodigoAcessoEmpresa);

               Intent intent = getIntent();
               finish();
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Checkbuilder.setNegativeButton("Sair", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = Checkbuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
 }
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNeworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNeworkInfo != null;
}



public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<RevistaModel>> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
      //  dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected List<RevistaModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("entrega");


                StringBuffer finalBuferedData = new StringBuffer();

                List<RevistaModel> revistaModelList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    RevistaModel revistaModel = new RevistaModel();
                    ///recebe os dados
                    revistaModel.setId(finalObject.getInt("Id_veiculo"));
                    revistaModel.setEdicao(finalObject.getString("Placa"));
                    revistaModel.setModelo(finalObject.getString("marca_modelo"));
                    revistaModel.setNome_cambio(finalObject.getString("Nome_cambio"));
                    revistaModel.setNome_Combustivel(finalObject.getString("Nome_Combustivel"));
                    revistaModel.setNome_cor(finalObject.getString("Nome_cor"));
                    revistaModel.setKM(finalObject.getString("KM"));
                    revistaModel.setVersao(finalObject.getString("Versao"));
                    revistaModel.setValor_deVenda(finalObject.getString("Valor_deVenda"));
                    revistaModel.setObservacoes(finalObject.getString("Observacoes"));

                    revistaModelList.add(revistaModel);
                }

                return revistaModelList;

            } // Try
            catch(MalformedInputException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }finally{
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RevistaModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //dialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new RevistaAdpter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        lvRevistas.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
public class RevistaAdpter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<RevistaModel> revistaModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RevistaAdpter(Context context, int resource, List<RevistaModel> objects){
        super(context, resource, objects);

        revistaModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        final String[] UrlRevista = new String[1];

        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.txPlaca         = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txPlaca);
            holder.txMarca_Modelo  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txMarcaModelo);

            lvRevistas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String Id_veiculo = String.valueOf(revistaModelList.get(position).getId());
                    String Placa = revistaModelList.get(position).getEdicao();
                    String MarcaModelo = revistaModelList.get(position).getModelo();
                    String Cambio = revistaModelList.get(position).getNome_cambio();
                    String Combustivel = revistaModelList.get(position).getNome_Combustivel();
                    String Cor = revistaModelList.get(position).getNome_cor();
                    String KM = revistaModelList.get(position).getKM();
                    String Versao = revistaModelList.get(position).getVersao();
                    String Valor_Venda = revistaModelList.get(position).getValor_deVenda();
                    String Observacao = revistaModelList.get(position).getObservacoes();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, detalhes_veiculo.class);

                    intent.putExtra("Id_veiculo", Id_veiculo); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Placa", Placa); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("MarcaModelo", MarcaModelo); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Cambio", Cambio); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Combustivel", Combustivel); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Cor", Cor); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("KM", KM); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Versao", Versao); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Valor_Venda", Valor_Venda); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Observacao", Observacao); //Optional parameters
                    intent.putExtra("Id_Empresa", CodigoAcessoEmpresa); //Optional parameters

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
holder.txPlaca.setText(revistaModelList.get(position).getEdicao());
holder.txMarca_Modelo.setText(revistaModelList.get(position).getModelo());
          return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{

        private TextView txPlaca;
        private TextView txMarca_Modelo;

    }
} } <code/>
```

neste caso aqui eu sei que está faltando alguma coisa na busca no adapter... alguém pode dar uma mão neste caso?... valeu

Comment: ja pensou em utilizar recycler view? é uma forma mais simples de se implementar.... basta colocar os métodos obrigatórios que tudo vai aparecer... não tem muito erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, não ficou muito claro qual erro que você está tendo, mas acredito que possa ter encontrado algo que possa te atrapalhar.
No seu método `getView` você está startando a Activity antes do setText dos seus textViews. Tenta então primeiro setar os textViews e depois startar a activity.

```
iholder.txPlaca.setText(revistaModelList.get(position).getEdicao());
holder.txMarca_Modelo.setText(revistaModelList.get(position).getModelo());

startActivity(intent)
```

Espero que possa ter ajudado :D